# Dispatch an action after other specific actions were dispatched and wait for state to change because of the first two actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to dispatch an action after other two actions were dispatched *AND* the state was changed because of those actions. I've read about `redux-saga` but I'm really looking forward to do it without it if possible (currently we're using `redux-thunk`).

I'm following a similar approach to the one Dan Abramov proposed in here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/723#issuecomment-139927639.

The actions are being executed  in the correct order, but the action inside the `then()` is executed *before* the state has changed due to firstActionDispatcher which the function that changes the state.

I'm using a promise.all using the next approach:

```
export const getData = categoryId => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    const elements = state.categories && state.categories.elements && state.categories.elements[categoryId];

    if (elements && elements.withMetadata) {
        return false;
    }

    return Promise.all([
        dispatch(firstActionDispatcher(categoryId)),
        dispatch(secondActionDispatcher)
    ])
    .then(() => dispatch({ type: THIRD_ACTION, data: Id }))
    .catch(error => window.newrelic.noticeError(new Error(`[Error] ${error}`)));
};
```

**Update Note 1:** `firstActionDispatcher` is returning a promise and same for `secondActionDispatcher`,

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now.

Comment: Actions are dispatched synchronously per https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1199 - so couldn't you dispatch the third action right after the other two? (Getting rid of the Promise)

Comment: firstActionDispatcher is returning a promise and same for secondActionDispatcher, they're fetching data that's why I'm using a `Promise.all`. @TrueWill I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: I know I'm late, but maybe you should return some value from these promises?
On the Github page you provided - same was happening when first two actions were not returning fetch, but only calling it

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a snippet of code you've provided you are doing this:

```
return Promise.all([
    dispatch(firstActionDispatcher(categoryId)),
    dispatch(secondActionDispatcher)
])
.then(() => dispatch({ type: THIRD_ACTION, data: Id }))
```

Please note that `secondActionDispatcher` is not being invoked.  I'm not sure if this is a typo, but you should likely be doing something like this:

```
return Promise.all([
    dispatch(firstActionDispatcher(categoryId)),
    dispatch(secondActionDispatcher())           // Notice the function call
])
.then(() => dispatch({ type: THIRD_ACTION, data: Id }))
```

Comment: It's being invoked correctly and the function is called, we're using the `dispatch()` method from the store, basically `dispatch(secondActionDispatcher)` is the same as `secondActionDispatcher(dispatch, state)`. @tpdietz